# Identifier Too Long Error Where Oracle Table is 34 charactersOracle ODBC ORA-00972: identifier is too Long

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, adodb

I have the following SQL which pulls against an Oracle ODBC:

```
SELECT t.INS_RQMT_PRODCT_NO, t.NEW_DEPT_NO 
FROM SUBMISSION_OBJECT_SEGMENTATION_REF t 
WHERE t.INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO IN (''6228506'')
```

I receive the following error when running in VBA:

[image]

I suspect it's from `SUBMISSION_OBJECT_SEGMENTATION_REF`. However, I have *no* control over the length of this database \ table name combination.

I have searched on line to get around it, but have not found any luck.

`SUBMISSION_OBJECT` is the database name. `SEGMENTATION_REF` is the table name.

I have also tried `SUBMISSION_OBJECT.SEGMENTATION_REF`, but no luck.

```
SELECT t.INS_RQMT_PRODCT_NO, t.NEW_DEPT_NO 
FROM SUBMISSION_OBJECT.SEGMENTATION_REF t 
WHERE t.INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO IN (''6228506'')
```

That produces

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

---

For reference, vba code that calls follows:

```
Function downloadsqltoexcel(conn As ADODB.Connection, sSQL As String, exceldestinationrangename As String, sqltablename As String, bDownload As Boolean, Optional ws As Worksheet) As Variant

Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs

    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open sSQL, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    '**** errors on above line ****
```

Comment: why are you doubling up the ticks? in your "in statement"?  should it be `WHERE t.INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO IN ('6228506')` instead?

Comment: @xQbert   I thought oracle needed double ticks unlike SQL needing only single.

Comment: Double quotes are generally used when you need to be case specific with a table/column or when there is a space in an object name.  oracle developers usually avoid spaces and use an underscore instead.

Comment: @xQbert - Thanks for reminder. It's been a little with oracle

Comment: Looks like your driver is doing you a disservice and capitalizing the alias AND putting quotes around it.  Change t in the code to T for alias and prefixes and try again?  If you have SQL developer or can directly connect/run query does it work there if so, then you likely have a driver issue.  What driver MSFT for oracle driver being used or oracle driver for oracle or something else?

Comment: could be driver: `Oracle in OraClient11g_home1` is the driver (32 bit). However, I can use driver to connect with Access and run queries there. Don't have SQLDeveloper installed currently. Capital "T" didn't help :(. Neither did take `T` alias away.

Comment: @xQbert - would you believe the error was syntax related. the column name in the where clause was `INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO` where it should have been `INS_RQMT_PRODCT_NO`. Glad I found it the issue, but man is that frustrating! Thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: I would with the error: T.INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO invalid identifier.  either T is invalid or the column name is ;P

Comment: @xQbert - Fair point. I kind of glossed over it since the `SELECT` syntax was correct. :(

Comment: Since the compiler executes the from clause then the where, then the select (for your select), we had to resolve the errors in order.  Thus we needed to fix from, then where then select.  you were just lucky enough to have errors in all 3. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use underscores to separate databases name from table names.  You use periods:

```
SELECT t.INS_RQMT_PRODCT_NO, t.NEW_DEPT_NO 
FROM SUBMISSION_OBJECT.SEGMENTATION_REF t 
WHERE t.INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO IN ('6228506')
```

Comment: I thought as such too. However, then I get a `missing right parenthesis error.

Comment: If I query exactly as you have written I get `"T"."INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO": invalid identifier.` AFAIK, Oracle needs double single quotes, correct?

Comment: "T" vs t.  somethings different between yours and the above. When using quotes oracle will keep table names/column names case sensitive.  In otherwords, don't use the quotes around the object names and it won't care if T or t is used.  the only time I ever really use them is in bad object design when a space exists or a keyword/reserved has been used.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman . . . Your original query had double single quotes in the `IN` list.  I replaced those with a single quote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes. I see that was wrong now, but I am getting `missing right parenthesis` error when I run this. Don't know why :(

Comment: The missing ) error was because the syntax for in is in ('val',...)  since you had '' it was looking for a , or a end ) instead it found ' thus the error.

Comment: so with the single quotes you get a missing ) error? or you get "T"."INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO": invalid identifier. ?

Comment: @xQbert - sorry for confusion :(. I get the "T"."INS_RQMT_PRODUCT_NO": invalid identifier error with single quote.

Comment: marking as answered as this solves the original question. I'll post a new question for other error.